Does this modification of the derivative after integral change the result?
Consider a two-variable real function $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ who has only one singularity point (0,0) in the domain of definition with
$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}f(x,y)=0,\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,y)=1.$
We are interested in the term $g(y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_{-d}^{d}{f(x,y)dx}$, where $d>0$. It is easy to see that $g(y) = 2d-2y\arctan{\frac{d}{y}}.$
There is discontinuity at $y=0.$ $\lim_{y\to 0^-}{g(y)} - \lim_{y\to 0^+}{g(y)} = 2\pi$. Now if we modify $f(x,y)$ into
$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2|1+(y+h(x)x^2)(2h(x)+h'(x)x)|}{x^2+(y+h(x)x^2)^2},$
where $h(x)$ is an analytical function.
Does the property $\lim_{y\to 0^-}{g(y)} - \lim_{y\to 0^+}{g(y)} = 2\pi$
still hold? How to prove it?
